# File systen broken after installing windows on top of debian

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot

I've had my Debian PC for some time now and just today, I decided to put windows as dual boot on it.

I have two disks:

- `/dev/sda` was my 1TB additional data drive
- `/dev/sdb` has my operating system on it

I firstly deleted all files from `/dev/sdb`, as I wanted to put Windows on that.
I had `/dev/sda` mounted under `/mnt/data/`, so I tried doing `sudo umount /mnt/data/`, I dont know if that did anything.

So I continued, used an USB stick to install Windows on the 1TB disk and everything worked fine. Windows 10 Pro installed onto the 1TB disk after I deleted the partitions from it using the Windows installation assistant thing, and I can now use Windows.

Later, I tried booting up Linux. I got as far as for Grub and then the Debian preboot launcher to start, which allowed me to select the Linux kernel (I think I'm using 5).

Soon after that however did I run into the problem: During boot Debian would run into an error with the disks and file system and boot into emergency mode. An image of the error: [image: image of error].

Now I don't know what to do, emergency mode runs just fine, I just can't figure out how to get Linux to forget the disk which was formerly `/dev/sda`. I don't understand the stuff with kernel patches one finds when searching online and I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I firstly deleted all files from /dev/sdb, as i wabted to put windows on that. I had /dev/sda mounted under /mnt/data/, so i tried doing sudo umount /mnt/data/, i dont know if that did anything.

`umount /mnt/data` unmounted the partition where you wanted to put Windows. But it didn't change the configuration to mount that partition at boot time. So now, when you boot, Linux wants to mount that partition, and before that it makes a sanity check. The error you're getting is on that sanity check, which makes sense since the partition no longer has a Linux filesystem on it.

You need to change the Linux configuration to either forget completely about that partition, or mount it but not insist that it's a Linux filesystem. Either way, you need to use an editor to edit the line containing `/mnt/data` in [`/etc/fstab`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/mount/fstab.5.en.html). Run the command

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

(You can use a different text mode editor if you prefer.)

The line needs to change to something like

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/data auto uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

- The first column is the partition. It's currently something like `LABEL=datapartition` but there's no partition by that label anymore. If the Windows partition has a label, you can use that; or you can use the partition number, which is probably 1, hence `/dev/sdb1`.
- The second column is the mount point, i.e. the directory where the files will be visible. You should probably change this to a different name like `/media/windows`. Note that you'll need to create this directory with `mkdir /media/windows`, otherwise you'll get an error at boot time again.
- The third column is the filesystem type. `auto` should work.
- The fourth column contains mount options. Above I put options to make all the files owned by user/group 1000. If you use a different user/group ID on Linux, replace 1000 by the correct value.
- The fifth and sixth column must be 0 for any filesystem that isn't owned by Linux. Alternatively, you can leave them out altogether.

If you'd prefer to fix this later in a more comfortable environment, you can just add `#` at the beginning of the line to comment it out, then save and boot normally.

Comment: Tried the long solution, now getting something along the lines of "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program". Gonna try the commenting out next...

Comment: Ok, just commenting it out worked, but will I have to work on how to uncomment it or can I just leave it commented?